# How do i create a function that scans multiple dataframe columns for a value. if any of those values are found the new column returns a given figure

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function

I'm trying to build a sheet whereby I have a new column ('column x').

This column would be populated by scanning over three already existing columns (a, b , c).

if a given value is found in any of those columns for the indexed figure the new column will read 'Fail' else it will read 'pass.

When i try this on scanning a single column my code works

example:

```
df["Column x"] = df["Column a"].apply(lambda val: "Fail" if val == 'T' else "Pass")
```

When i try in more than one it fails no matter how i adjust.

```
df['Column x'] = df['Column a'].any(lambda val: 'Fail' if val == 0 else 'Pass') or df['Column b'].apply(lambda val: 'Fail' if val == 'False' else 'Pass')
```

any advise is incredibly helpful

Comment: what kind of error are you getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an all pandas code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1':['A','B','C'],
    'col2':['E','F','G'],
    'col3':['H','I','J']}
)

df["C"] = pd.Series(
    df['col1'].apply(lambda a: 0 if a == 'C' else 1) &
    df['col2'].apply(lambda a: 0 if a == 'C' else 1) &
    df['col3'].apply(lambda a: 0 if a == 'C' else 1)
).apply(lambda x: "Pass" if x else 'Fail')
print(df)
```

output

```
    col1 col2 col3     C
0    A    E    H     Pass
1    B    F    I     Pass
2    C    G    J     Fail
```

Handling empty data frame

```
if df.empty:
    print('DataFrame is empty!')
```

Comment: @kiki833 If this helps, please mark the answer as an ok, it helps other people plus the one who answers

Comment: Also, since you might have to apply the same code on multiple columns, it would be better to write a separate answer rather than a lambda to make code more clean

Comment: Thank you for your great advise. on your lasst point on multiple columns do you mind explaining more what you mean? as i do indeed have to apply similar code on multiple columns

Comment: is there an additional tweak to make to the code you shared to give a different result if data is unavailable? Sometimes there is no data

Comment: What I mean is that writing the same lambda function, again and again, is tedious and makes code look unclean, so what you can do is create a function and call it. I guess you could just write a lambda function and assign it to a variable and then call that variable

Comment: What kind of result would you like if there is no data? If you would like to raise an error of sort, you could just write a function and check if df is empty using its length and raise ValuError or something before applying these conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Check Below code with **np.where**, checking for **J** if present in any column than **False** else **True**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['A','B','C'],'col2':['E','F','G'],'col3':['H','I','J']})

df['column_x'] = np.where(((df['col1']=='J')|(df['col2']=='J')|(df['col3']=='J')),'Fail','Pass')

df
```

Output:

[image]